# Remove &nbsp; in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, replace

I have var called htmlcode:

```
  <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3"><img width="600" height="60" alt="" src="nieuwsbrief_banner.gif</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

I want to remove all occurrences of `&nbsp;`. I am able to replace other characters in a string, but can't seem to replace `&nbsp;` into an empty string (""). I did this:

```
<cfset htmlcode = Replace(htmlcode, "&nbsp;", "", "all")>
```

I also tried replacing `nbsp;` (without the & in the beginning). The result was that all `&nbsp;` were changed into `&amp;`. I then tried `<cfset htmlcode = ReplaceNoCase(htmlcode, "&amp;", "", "all")>` but this didn't remove any occurrences of `&amp;`.

What should do?

Comment: what result are you getting, and what are you expecting? also, you could try `replacenocase` to rule out case sensitivity.

Comment: What is it that makes you think you're doing something wrong? How does your result here differ from your expectations? You need to provide this sort of information.  A &NBSP; is just a sequence of characters, it has no special meaning in a string, so your code is fine. One consideration: replace() is case-sensitive, so will not replace &NBSP; or &Nbsp; etc.

Comment: It returns the string without any modifications. I tried replacenocase: no difference

Comment: you may have your arguments around the wrong way: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_34.html

Comment: @AdamCameron well i expect the returned string to have no `&nbsp;` containing.

Comment: The replace function works; if you tell it to replace a specific six character string, it will do. I would guess the htmlcode variable actually contains a double-encoded `&amp;nbsp;` and you're not encoding it when outputting, so it looks like `&nbsp;` when it's not.

Comment: Update the question to show exactly what the input string is, and exactly what the output string is (this should have been part of your own troubleshooting, btw). Basically post some stand-alone, working code that demonstrates your issue. Bear in mind that what displays in the browser is not necessarily what the string contains. Do not rely on the browser-render to determine what the string contains: look at the actual string (possibly just via view-source will do). @Antony: the usage of `replace()` is correct in the above example.

Comment: @PeterBoughton it looks the problem has to do with the &. because when i replace all `nbsp;` (without the &). it works. 
@AdamCameron i updated my question. please have a look. thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you do as you've been advised and check to see if you've actually got "&nbsp;" or "&amp;nbsp;"? Basically your input string doesn't have what you think it has in it (and what you're suggesting to us it has in it): if I copy and paste your code, and make it a stand-alone self-contained repro case, it works absolutely fine. Check what's in the string. Not just by *looking* at it, but check it char by char and check the character codes if needs must.

Answer (score 6):

To strip &nbsp you need to search for chr code 160.

```
<cfset htmlcode = Replace(htmlcode, chr(160), "", "all")>
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20180305075110/http://www.cjboco.com/blog.cfm/post/table-of-ascii-characters-and-symbols-for-coldfusion

Answer (score 0):

used the below and it work. You should check your variable name and ensure you are re-assigning the fixed string to the variable. Had the same issue while testing and trying to answer your question.

```
<cfset htmlcode = Replace(htmlcode, "&nbsp;", " ", 'all')>
```

If it doesn't work still, look at the function `HTMLEditFormat`

Comment: That would strip out *any* HTML entities, not just &nbsp;. One doesn't need a regex for this, the simple replace() is fine.

Comment: thank you for the correction @AdamCameron. i came up with that after i couldn't get the first to work. Apparently, i was making the mistake i described in my edit. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Nicemister,

I know it's frustrating but the truth is that the replace code above does work with the string you have posted. Check this out.

```
<Cfsavecontent variable="myhtml">
<table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3">some image</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>


</Cfsavecontent>

<cfoutput>#myhtml#</cfoutput>
<hr>
<Cfset myHTML = Replace(myhtml, "&nbsp;", "", "all")>

<Cfoutput>#myhtml#</CFOUTPUT>
```

You can view the result at this URL.

http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/test/myhtml.cfm

Go to "view source" and you will see - the first table has spaces and the second does not. As suspect (as Peter and Adam and Ray have said) that your input "Htmlcode" variable does NOT contain the string `&nbsp;` that you believe it does.

Also note, in the code above you are missing a closing tag for your img.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<cfset htmlcode = Replace(htmlcode, " ", "", "all")>
```

If you html code contains textarea, &nbsp wil not be "detected".

Paste this code [Here](http://cflive.net/):

```
<cfoutput>
<cfsavecontent variable="htmlcode">
textarea:<textarea>1 2&nbsp;2</textarea><br />
div:<div>1&nbsp;2&nbsp;</div>
</cfsavecontent>
before:<br />
#htmlcode# <br />
<cfset htmlcode = Replace(htmlcode, "&nbsp;", "", "all")>
after:<br />
#htmlcode#
<cfset htmlcode = Replace(htmlcode, " ", "", "all")>
after after:<br />
#htmlcode#
</cfoutput>
```

You can see that your replace perfectly working, but not on textarea.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The CFML server doesn't know what a `<textarea>` is, all it sees is a string, so that the string has a `<textarea>` in it is neither here nor there. The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is because you're looking at what the browser renders, not what's in the actual string.

Comment: @nicemister updated the question, I thought that he might have troubles with rendering in browser.